# How to get mutable struct from HashMap?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a hashmap for all my states, which is a `HashMap<String, Rc<State>>`, and I want to call the current state's member `fn init(&mut self)`. But I'm getting an error with the following code:

```
...
if let Some(state) = self.states.get_mut(state_id) {
    (*state).init();
}
...
```

Here's the error:

```
src/main.rs:70:25: 70:33 error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable
src/main.rs:70                         (*state).shutdown();`
```

afaict from the documentation, the problem is that `get_mut` returns a mutable reference to the state, not a reference to a mutable state. So how would I get a reference to a mutable state?

Comment: Does `if let Some(mut state) = self.states.get_mut(state_id) {` help?

Comment: Nope, tried that already. Oh, and I got it working using `RefCell`s, but I'd rather not use them because they are slower, and could easily panic if I'm not extremely careful.

Comment: You seem to want interior mutability then. [Playpen example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7f4cf297788faca19d75&version=stable)

Comment: Yeah, I was just hoping there was a static solution. =(

Comment: It would be possible if you weren't using `Rc`, but even [the `Rc` documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/rc/#examples) uses `RefCell`s for interior mutability.

Comment: yea this has nothing todo with `HashMap`. Rust cannot reason about the mutability of an `Rc`'s inner value, therefor it forbids mutation as long as the `Rc` is not unique. You can use `get_mut` if there's only a single reference. But then you might as well drop the `Rc` alltogether

Comment: Your error message references code that you don't include.

Comment: @Shien: For a static solution, you need to forego aliasing; do you actually need `Rc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fundamental idea in Rust is: **either Aliasing or Mutability, but not both.**

Aliasing means having multiple active pointers to the same value.

What is `Rc<T>`? It's sharing ownership, aliasing a value. Thus `Rc<T>` does not allow mutating the value inside.

There is a way around this with `Rc`, to use **interior mutability** with types like either `Cell<U>` or `RefCell<U>`.

(If you write a multithreaded program, you'd use `Arc` for thread safe shared ownership / aliasing, and you could use `Mutex<U>` for thread safe interior mutability instead.)

- `Rc<Cell<U>>` allows mutating `U` by only allowing write-in and read-out, but no pointers to the inner `U` value. No pointers, no aliasing!
- `Rc<RefCell<U>>` allows mutating by the method `.borrow_mut()` that will keep a borrow count at runtime and dynamically make sure that any mutable borrow is exclusive. No aliasing, you have mutability!

Links

- [Rust Book: Choosing your guarantees (Cell types)](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/choosing-your-guarantees.html#cell-types)
- A look back in Rust's history: [Imagine Never Hearing the Phrase ‘Aliasable, Mutable’ Again (2012)](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2012/11/18/imagine-never-hearing-the-phrase-aliasable/)