# Maintaining a mutable reference to struct in HashMap

Tags: rust

Is it possible to borrow a mutable reference to the contents of a HashMap and use it for an extended period of time without impeding read-only access?

This is for trying to maintain a window into the state of various components in a system that are running independently (via Tokio) and need to be monitored.

As an example:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Container {
    running : bool,
    count : u8
}

impl Container {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        for i in 1..100 {
            self.count = i;
        }

        self.running = false;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    let mut container = Arc::new(
        Box::new(
            Container {
                running: true,
                count: 0
            }
        )
    );

    map.insert(0, container.clone());

    container.run();

    map.remove(&0);
}
```

This is for a Tokio-driven program where multiple operations will be happening asynchronously and visibility into the overall state of them is required.

There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790411/how-to-get-mutable-struct-from-hashmap) where a temporary mutable reference can be borrowed, but that won't work as the `run()` function needs time to complete.

Comment: I get an impression that you are dealing with multiple threads. If that is the case, you have other options to provide "exclusive write or read access" at any point of time using Mutex or RwLock.

Comment: @apatniv It's just not clear how compatible those are when the structure in question is located inside something like `HashMap`. In C++ I could just dump in a pointer and mutate it freely in one thread etc, but not in Rust.

Comment: Do you want the structure to cross thread boundary or are these within a given thread? If these are within a given thread, then don't need Arc. Rc is really required if you have multiple owners to the same structure.

Comment: @apatniv Tokio tends to employ threads for particular things so using `Arc` to be safe.

Comment: If you need to access your struct from multiple threads, then [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [RwLock](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) are the way to go. If it's all in a single thread, then [RefCell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) will allow you to "_have multiple references to an object and yet mutate it_".

Comment: @Jmb That works for short-term access, especially RwLock, but is there a way to keep a mutable reference to something inside `HashMap`? It looks like there's some upcoming changes to how those work, where you can get a reference back to the thing that's inserted, but those are listed as unstable.

Comment: @Jmb The alternative is to have some kind of other state object pushed into there, and the struct that's operating uses something private, periodically updating that data with an RwLock type access method, but that seems convoluted.

Comment: There is no way to have a live mutable reference at the same time as other references. Or in other words at the time you mutate the value, there **must not** be any other live reference to the same value. `RwLock` and `RefCell` allow you to store a non-mutable reference somewhere (which allows other references to exist) and only make it mutable at the instant it needs to change (provided there are no other references at that point).

Comment: @Jmb Ah, so you're limited to *either* a mutable reference or multiple immutable ones, but not both? I thought it limited you to one writer only, with unlimited readers, but I may be confusing that conceptually with something else.

Comment: how would you handle write and read in the same time if this would be the case ? that why mutex exist in C++ too.

Comment: Can you use an [atomic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/) here? `Container` is small enough to fit in a single word.

Comment: @Stargateur Still trying to unlearn a lot of bad C++ habits due to Rust calling me out on my mistakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on suggestions from Jmb and Stargateur reworked this to use a `RwLock` internally. These internals could be reworked by having methods that manipulate them, but the basics are here:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::RwLock;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ContainerState {
    running : bool,
    count : u8
}

struct Container {
    state : Arc<RwLock<ContainerState>>
}

impl Container {
    fn run(&self) {
        for i in 1..100 {
            let mut state = self.state.write().unwrap();
            state.count = i;
        }

        {
            let mut state = self.state.write().unwrap();

            state.running = false;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    let state = Arc::new(
        RwLock::new(
            ContainerState {
                running: true,
                count: 0
            }
        )
    );

    map.insert(0, state);

    let container = Container {
        state: map[&0].clone()
    };

    container.run();

    println!("Final state: {:?}", map[&0]);

    map.remove(&0);
}
```

Where the key thing I was missing is you can have a mutable reference *or* multiple immutable references, and they're mutually exclusive. My initial understanding was that these two limits were independent.